# select query fails on large dataset i sqlcontext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My code is reading data from sqlcontext. The table has 20 million records in it. I want to calculate totalCount in table.

```
val finalresult = sqlContext.sql(“SELECT movieid,
tagname, occurrence AS eachTagCount, count AS
totalCount FROM result ORDER BY movieid”)
```

I want calculate the total count of one column without using groupby and save it in a textfile.
.I change my saving file without additional ]

```
 >val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext._
case class DataClass(UserId: Int, MovieId:Int, Tag: String)
// Create an RDD of DataClass objects and register it as a table.
val Data = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/tagupdate").map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim.toInt, p(2).trim)).toDF()
Data.registerTempTable("tag")

val orderedId = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId AS Id,Tag FROM tag ORDER BY MovieId")
orderedId.rdd
  .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+";"+_))
  .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output")
  // orderedId.write.parquet("ordered.parquet")
val eachTagCount =orderedId.groupBy("Tag").count()
//eachTagCount.show()
eachTagCount.rdd
 .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+";"+_))
 .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output2")
```

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 604) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at tags$$anonfun$6.apply(tags.scala:46) at tags$$anonfun$6.apply(tags.scala:46) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)

Comment: What exactly is your question? it is highly likely that the answer is in your post where it says ```NumberFormatException: For input string: "10]"```

Comment: reason of this exception and how to correct it

Comment: Then the answer is definitely in your original post.

Comment: i want to calculate total count of one column without using groupby and save it in textfile

Comment: Then once you have worked past this problem have a try at doing that and if you get stuck then ask another question showing the code that you have written along with your specific question. Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error `NumberFormatException` is probably thrown in this place:

```
p(1).trim.toInt
```

It is thrown because you're trying to parse `10]` which is obviously not a valid number.

- You could try to find that problematic place in your file and just remove additional `]`.
- You could also try to catch an error and provide a default value in case there are any problems with parsing:

  ```
  import scala.util.Try

  Try(p(1).trim.toInt).getOrElse(0) //return 0 in case there is problem with parsing.
  ```
- Another thing you could do is to remove characters, which are not digits from the string you're trying to parse:

  ```
  //filter out everything which is not a digit
  p(1).filter(_.isDigit).toInt)
  ```

It might also fail in case everything will be filtered out and an empty string will be left, so it might be a good idea to also wrap it in `Try`.

Comment: thanks@Krzysztof Atłasik .I change my saving file without additional ] using           eachTagCount.rdd
 .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+";"+_))
 .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output2") but another exception appear                                                                                              ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 604)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at tags$$anonfun$6.apply(tags.scala:46)
 at tags$$anonfun$6.apply(tags.scala:46)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
 any help

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add this error?